# How to sort results by matching todays date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to order my data by todays date in my column date is stored as 2020-08-18 so if a callback date which was set is todays date i wish to first show those results on top. i tried

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$records    = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE status = 'Callback' ORDER BY callback_date LIKE '$today', id DESC LIMIT $start, $records_per_page");
```

But its not working, could someone help here?

Thanks

Comment: Your `LIKE '$today'` should be part of your WHERE clause. Something along the lines of `$records = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE status = 'Callback' AND callback_date LIKE '$today' ORDER BY callback_date, id DESC LIMIT $start, $records_per_page");`

Comment: what datatype is callback_date ?

Comment: i store it as varchar

Comment: doing so i get a blank page

Comment: Are there any future dates in your table? If not you can just `ORDER BY callback_date DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current date with [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) so there is no need for `'$today'`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE status = 'Callback' 
ORDER BY callback_date = CURRENT_DATE DESC, id DESC 
LIMIT $start, $records_per_page
```

The Boolean expression `callback_date = CURRENT_DATE` evaluates to `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`, so by setting the order `DESC` you get today's rows on top.

Comment: Thanks alot @forpas this helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION of two inner query like below.

```
Select * from (
  SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE status = 'Callback' and  callback_date = '2020-08-18'
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE status = 'Callback' and  callback_date <> '2020-08-18'
  ORDER BY callback_date, id DESC
)x LIMIT $start, $records_per_page
```